# Hide a custom action button after 14 days in WooCommerce orders page in my account

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom action button "Request Refund" on orders page of my-account in WooCommerce. I was looking, is there any way to hide this button after 14-days since order gets completed.

I have searched a lot, but no similar solution. Any help will be appreciated.

**Here is my code:**

```
function add_request_refund($actions, $order)
{
    if ($order->has_status('completed'))
    {
        $actions['refund_request'] = array(
            'url' => url_of_request_refund($order),
            'name' => __('Request Refund', 'my-textdomain'),
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_request_refund', 100, 2);

function url_of_request_refund($order)
{

    $page_id = 4007;
    $refund_url = trailingslashit(get_page_link($page_id)) . '?order=' . $order->get_order_number();
    return $refund_url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add_request_refund( $actions, $order ) {
    $order_date = $order->order_date;
    $getTodayDate = date('m/d/Y');
    $date1 = date_create($order_date);
    $date2 = date_create($getTodayDate);

      //difference between two dates
     $diff = date_diff($date2,$date1);


    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) && $diff->days < 15 ) {
    $actions['refund_request'] = array(
        'url'  => url_of_request_refund( $order ),
        'name' => __( 'Request Refund', 'my-textdomain' ),
    );
}
return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_request_refund', 100, 2 );

function url_of_request_refund( $order ) {

$page_id = 4007;
$refund_url = trailingslashit( get_page_link( $page_id ) ) . '?order=' . $order->get_order_number();
return $refund_url;
}
```

This should work. Tested at my side!

Comment: We can use `$order_date = $order->completed_date;` instead, to calculate the days since the order gets completed.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to hide the button after 14 days from the order date then
> you can just add a small check to your if block and that will do.

Here is the sample code:

```
function add_request_refund($actions, $order)
{
    $order_date = date_create($order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d'));
    $current_date = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));


    $diff = date_diff($order_date, $current_date);
    //print_r($diff);

    if ($order->has_status('completed') && ($diff->days <= 14)) //check this line
    {
        $actions['refund_request'] = array(
        'url'  => url_of_request_refund( $order ),
            'name' => __('Request Refund', 'my-textdomain'),
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_request_refund', 100, 2);
```

Reference: [date_diff()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp)